# Ofbiz unable to acquire a new connection from DB

Tags: mysql, connection-pooling, ofbiz

I'm using ofbiz with MySQL. Now a days frequently i'm getting connection pool problem.
The stack trace saying that it is unable to acquire a new connection from DB. 
This causing me to restart my server for every 5 days or 7 days.

I think, As ofbiz taking care of connections we don't need to do anything other than performing operations with delegator.

Due to this problem i have increased my pool-maxsize to 500 in entityengine.xml file. After that it worked fine for 20 days. Then again it showing the same error in log and giving 503 errors to users.
As we are not opening and closing connections i don't know what to do. How to resolve this problem. Or is there any way to resolve it from DB side.

Thanks in advance.